# 'list' object has no attribute 'map' in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I'm new in pyspark .
I write this code in pyspark:

```
def filterOut2(line):
    return [x for x in line if x != 2]
filtered_lists = data.map(filterOut2)
```

but  I get this error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'map'
```

How do I perform a `map` operation specifically on my data in PySpark in a way that allows me to filter my data to only those values for which my condition evaluates to true?

Comment: what is type of `data`?

Comment: Can you add more code snippets?

Comment: like this :data = [[1,2,3,5],[1,2,5,2],[3,5,2,8],[6,3,1,2],[5,3,2,5],[4,1,2,5]]

Comment: do this `filtered_lists  = map(filterOut2, data)`

Comment: i get this error : map() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: @zahra you've shadowed the built-in `map` with some. What does `print(repr(map))`  give you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map(filterOut2, data)` works:

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3,5],[1,2,5,2],[3,5,2,8],[6,3,1,2],[5,3,2,5],[4,1,2,5] ]
... def filterOut2(line):
...     return [x for x in line if x != 2]
... list(map(filterOut2, data))
...
[[1, 3, 5], [1, 5], [3, 5, 8], [6, 3, 1], [5, 3, 5], [4, 1, 5]]
```

> map() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Looks like you redefined `map`. Try `__builtin__.map(filterOut2, data)`.

Or, use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [filterOut2(line) for line in data]
[[1, 3, 5], [1, 5], [3, 5, 8], [6, 3, 1], [5, 3, 5], [4, 1, 5]]
```

Comment: thank you . it work with:   `__builtin__.map(filterOut2, data)`

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.